# Undefined error in ajax json methods

Tags: c#, ajax, json

I have a problem with a `json` method and it gives me this error. 
This is my code:

```
function test() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'zz.aspx/GetDate',
                //processData: false,
                data: "{'keyWord':" + keyWord + "}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {   
                    if (msg.length > 0) {


                        $("#suggestions").fadeIn();
                        $("#suggestions").html(msg);

                        setTimeout('ToogleAct();', 500);
                    } else {
                        $("#suggestions").fadeOut();
                        $('#actions').css('display', 'none');
                        alert('ERROR [sasa ]');
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert('ERROR [ ' + error + ' ]');
                }
            });

        } else {
            $("#suggestions").fadeOut();
        }
    }
```

and this is c# Code:

```
 public static string GetDate(string keyWord)
    {

        string S = "";
        DataTable dt = DataLayer.Maghale.Search(keyWord).Tables[0];
        S += "<div id=\"SGR\" style=\"height: auto;\"><div id=\"APL\">";
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            S += "<a href=\"" + dr["Alias"].ToString() + "\">" +
                "<div class=\"imageholder\"> " +
                "<img src=\"~/MakeThumbnail.aspx?file=~/Images/CustomImages/Seo-S.png&i=80&j=80\")\"></div>" +
                "<span class=\"SGSH1\">" + dr["Title"].ToString() + "</span>" +
                "<span class=\"SGSH2\"> " + dr["Description"].ToString().Substring(0, 15) + " ... </span></a>";
        }
        S += "</div></div>";
        return S;
    }
```

When I use type:Post;
then my msg.Length>0 return false
why did it happen and what should I do to return my string back and put it in html?

And when I use type=GET:
give me Undefined Error
which is the difference between Post And Get and when I should use get or post
Please tell me, thanks

Comment: try `dataType: "text"` to receive the correct format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to properly set up your ajax calls. You are passing a string to `data` of ajax which is valid but I guess you want to access submitted value using 'keyWord' variable on server side. Change `data` of ajax as below:

```
data: { keyWord: $.trim($("#txtSearchBox").val()) },
```

Also, change `setTimeout('ToogleAct();', 500);` to `setTimeout(ToogleAct, 500);`

Comment: tnx but the KeyWord Is Just The TextBox Like This: keyWord = $.trim($("#txtSearchBox").val()); i dont Understand what you say

Comment: tnx that solve my pro.but now another problem.! when i type some integer in textbox return me the answer but when i type string value return me Undefined error, i try JSON.stringify and jQuery.parseJSON() and the problem not solved

Comment: i put  the break point in first line of c#,i think the in this phase not go to server side,the c# side not execute

Comment: change code as i mentioned. Then tell me if that solved your issue.

Comment: setTimeout not work any thing solved ,but the string datatype stil be a problem

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at this link, you'll get the full description of `post` v `get` http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html

> The HTML specifications technically define the difference between
>   "GET" and "POST" so that former means that form data is to be encoded
>   (by a browser) into a URL while the latter means that the form data is
>   to appear within a message body. But the specifications also give the
>   usage recommendation that the "GET" method should be used when the
>   form processing is "idempotent", and in those cases only. As a
>   simplification, we might say that "GET" is basically for just getting
>   (retrieving) data whereas "POST" may involve anything, like storing or
>   updating data, or ordering a product, or sending E-mail.

In you success, check for `msg.d`, use chrome developer tools or firebug to check what you receive back.

One other thing I'd suggest, is to use `StringBuilder` class when using string concatenation. So, instead of `string +=`, you would have `StringBuilder.Append` which is more efficient.

Comment: tnx now i know the differences,but what is the Undefin error ??i programming the auto complete search and i need get type

Comment: yes,but another problem appear,please see the comments of below answer

Comment: Are you saying that the c# method GetDate is not being hit?

Comment: when i put text value in textbox yes,but when i type int value in textbox it work currectly

Comment: Try wrapping the textbox in json.stringify() had your code from the initial post been updated? By the way, updating means clicking the up arrow next to an answer, not accepting the answer. Only accept answers once it solved the problem to your question.